# How to get the dates between two dates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a start date and end date . I need to get all the dates in between  these two dates. One more condition is it should return the dates based on split ways, ie it can be week basis, day basis, hour basis,Month basis

I have checked the pandas date_range function but its returning only the ending of all the date series.

```
time_range = pandas.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='W')
```

This is returning only the starting of each week(start date), not the ending week(end_date).

Example :

```
time_range = pandas.date_range('2018-01-01 00:00:00', '2018-03-23 00:00:00', freq='W')

Result:
['2018-01-06 00:00:00Z', '2018-01-13 00:00:00Z', '2018-01-20 00:00:00Z', '2018-01-27 00:00:00Z', '2018-02-03 00:00:00Z', '2018-02-10 00:00:00Z', '2018-02-17 00:00:00Z', '2018-02-24 00:
00:00Z', '2018-03-03 00:00:00Z', '2018-03-10 00:00:00Z', '2018-03-17 00:00:00Z']
```

I need both start date and end of the week ie in this case

```
'2018-01-01 00:00:00Z' - '2018-01-06 00:00:00Z'
'2018-01-07 00:00:00Z' - '2018-01-13 00:00:00Z'
'2018-01-14 00:00:00Z' - '2018-01-20 00:00:00Z'
'2018-01-21 00:00:00Z' - '2018-01-27 00:00:00Z'
'2018-02-28 00:00:00Z' - '2018-02-03 00:00:00Z'
```

---------- and so on

Answer (score 2):

Here is a numpy solution using "business" day filtering with a custom `weekmask`:

```
>>> all_days = np.arange('1970-02-05', '1970-05-08', dtype='M8[D]')
>>> week_start_end = all_days[np.is_busday(all_days, weekmask='Mon Sun')]
>>> week_start_end
array(['1970-02-08', '1970-02-09', '1970-02-15', '1970-02-16',
       '1970-02-22', '1970-02-23', '1970-03-01', '1970-03-02',
       '1970-03-08', '1970-03-09', '1970-03-15', '1970-03-16',
       '1970-03-22', '1970-03-23', '1970-03-29', '1970-03-30',
       '1970-04-05', '1970-04-06', '1970-04-12', '1970-04-13',
       '1970-04-19', '1970-04-20', '1970-04-26', '1970-04-27',
       '1970-05-03', '1970-05-04'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

This only works for weeks. For other units:

```
>>> def first_last_range(start, stop, step='M', resolution='D'):
...     large = np.arange(start, stop, dtype=f'M8[{step}]')
...     first = large.astype(f'M8[{resolution}]')
...     last = (large + np.timedelta64(1, step)).astype(f'M8[{resolution}]') - np.timedelta64(1, resolution)
...     full = np.c_[first, last].ravel()
...     return full[full[0] < np.datetime64(start) : len(full) - (full[-1] > np.datetime64(stop))]
... 
>>> 
>>> first_last_range('1970-02-05', '1970-05-08')
array(['1970-02-28', '1970-03-01', '1970-03-31', '1970-04-01',
       '1970-04-30'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

Please note that you may want to adapt end point semantics to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the solution ,How can I use the same for hour, day and month basis. Could you please update

Answer (score 1):

Could this be what you were looking for:

```
import itertools

start_end = [pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='W-MON').tolist(), pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='W-SUN').tolist()]

date_range = pd.DatetimeIndex(itertools.chain.from_iterable(start_end))
```

Comment: this will almost close to what I am looking for. Thank you for the solution .can you please update if in case it is month or day or hour instead of week ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas.Timedelta` and vectorized operations and do something like:

```
import pandas

start_dates = pandas.date_range("2018-01-01", "2018-03-23", freq="W")
end_dates = start_dates + pandas.Timedelta(weeks=1)

starts_list = start_dates.astype(str).tolist()
ends_list = end_dates.astype(str).tolist()

print(list(zip(starts_list, ends_list)))
```

If the `start` date is the start of your week, you will get the first day and the last day for each week. By editing the parameter of `Timedelta` and the `freq` parameter of `date_range` you can easily adapt its behavior to do the same for a month period for example.

Answer (score 0):

What results are you getting? And what results are you expecting?

It seems to work for me:

```
import pandas as pd
time_range = pd.date_range("2018-01-01", "2018-02-01", freq='W')
print(time_range)
DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-07', '2018-01-14', '2018-01-21', '2018-01-28'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='W-SUN')
```

Comment: Even its is working for me too :) . But if you check the results its is returning  only the week ending, not the week starting

Comment: What results are you getting? And what results are you expecting? Post an example.

Comment: `time_range = pd.date_range("2018-01-01", "2018-02-01", freq='W-SUN')` and `time_range = pd.date_range("2018-01-01", "2018-02-01", freq='W-MON')` should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can get a list of date by running looking at the `timedelta`

```
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
d0=datetime.strptime("2018-01-01","%Y-%m-%d")
d1= datetime.strptime("2018-02-01", "%Y-%m-%d")
l=[]
for days in range((d1-d0).days):
    l.append(str((d0 + timedelta(days)).date()))
```

now `l` is a list of all dates between d0 and d1
to split it by week is easy, and I leave that to you, if you are having issues with other kinds of splits please post a follow up question, but it's pretty straight